# Siri to lock screen and take screenshot?

Tags: iphone, siri, screen-lock

Apparently, the power button has become pretty insensitive in my iPhone 5. When I say "lock screen" or "take screenshot", I want that iPhone does such activity. Now when I say them, iPhone just googles them that is very stupid. So how can I make Siri to lock screen, screenshot and hopefully other things?

Answer (score 2):

Currently Siri can't do these actions.

One possibility is to enable assistiveTouch :

- Settings
- General
- Accessibility
- AssistiveTouch

---

On the assistive touch button :

- Device > next > screenshoot.
- Device > next > lock screen

Comment: Perhaps there is an application that locks screen so I could call an application to do it? Siri definitely finds for application. There must be a solution.

Comment: without a jailbreak, no app can lock the screen.

Comment: Awesome! Assistive Touch helps a lot until I get the power button replaced, found screenshot and lock-screen in Assistive Touch, nice app! 14 days' queue in Apple to replace the power button :(